# using pointer to inline function vs using pointer to function

Tags: c++, function, inline

I want to pass pointers of some functions to a template class to use them later. I was wondering if:

Does it make a possibly (speed-wise) beneficial difference if I make these functions inline?

Functions themselves are possibly one line wrapper for another functions like the example below:

```
//inline ?
void func_wrapper_1(){
    func1(arg1);
}
//inline ?
void func_wrapper_2(){
    func2(arg2);
}
```

and the class template is like the example below:

```
template<void(*f1)(), void(*f2)()>
class caller{
public:
    static void func(int v){
        if(v) {
            (*f1)();
        }else{
            (*f2)();
        }
    }
};
```

And later on in the `main` function it will be used like the example below:

```
    caller<func_wrapper_1,func_wrapper_2>::func(0);
    caller<func_wrapper_1,func_wrapper_2>::func(1);
```

I know that every things depends on compiler and compiling option, but lets assume compiler accepts to make these functions inline.

Comment: If you want to pass pointers, they can't, *by definition*, be inline. They need to be stand-alone so you can reference them by a pointer. Inlined functions may be subject to all kinds of contextual optimization that makes them impossible to use this way.

Comment: Since this is C++, why not `std::function` or use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)? You won't need the template class. That's also not much of a template class given the template arguments aren't generic.

Comment: @tadman , yes thank you. this is what I want to know( "they can't, by definition, be inline") . so let say, I also use these wrapper functions themselves some where else too. actually I was thinking of using std::function

Comment: Like you *can* inline them *if* you're declaring a regular function, no templates involved, that calls one or both of them. You can't if you're making that decider function really generic and make it use function pointers. It's worth noting that you create two instances of this thing with identical arguments rather than just calling the same thing twice.

Comment: If you made your template parameters *callable types* I suspect it might be possible to benefit from inlining.

Comment: @Galik callable types!? could you please elaborate?

Comment: @tadman the real thing is going to be much more complex than this example

Comment: @AKL You can create a `class`/`struct` which overloads the *function call operator* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator

Comment: You might want to give us a bit more context here as I think this example is far too trivial to make a proper assessment on.

Comment: The `inline` keyword in front of a function is nowadays is only used to tell that a definition exists in multiple translation units so that you don’t get a linking error. But has no effect on whether the compiler/linker will perform inlining or not.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a compiler will be smart enough to inline a given situation is up for grabs but I think it may be possible by creating *Callable Types* by overloading the [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator).

Something like this:

```
template<typename Func1, typename Func2>
class caller{
public:
    static void func(int v){
        if(v) {
            // Func1() - creates an object of type Func1
            // that object is 'called' using the '()' operator
            Func1()();
        }else{
            Func2()();
        }
    }
};

struct CallableType1
{
    // overloading the function call operator makes objects of
    // this type callable
    void operator()() const { std::cout << "callable 1" << '\n'; }
};

struct CallableType2
{
    void operator()() const { std::cout << "callable 2" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    caller<CallableType1, CallableType2> cc;

    cc.func(2);
}
```

Comment: Interesting Technic! but in this way, for each call, first the object must be constructed and then the function should be called, which might just add up to the overheads. Also wasn't the name of this Technic functor?

Comment: @AKL Given that there is nothing to construct (the objects require no memory) I was hoping the compiler would forgo all that. Otherwise you could make them member variables, but you will have to make the function that calls them non-static. Yes, they used to be called *functors*.